# How can I add a custom search engine to Chrome (beta, stable...)?

Tags: settings, chrome-for-android, search, browser-add-ons, chromium

Call me dumb, but, I don't see an obvious way to do this.

I want to add duckduckgo.com as the main search engine in Google Chrome for Android (beta, stable...)

Answer (score 4):

As of chrome v39, this still can't easily be done; however, you can hack it. From  the XDA post SomeNickName referenced:

1. Install a Terminal emulator or use `adb shell` if you're familiar with it.
2. Change the "last_known_google_url" and "last_prompted_google_url" settings support having a `search&q=`added to the end. For example, duckduckgo would work with, `https://www.duckduckgo.com&` -- where the extra ampersand at the end is for converting the "search" text into an additional query sting param.

Here's a shell command for setting the duckduckgo url:

```
    p='/data/data/com.chrome.beta/app_chrome/Default/Preferences'
    awk '/last_known_google_url/ {sub(/google.com\//,"duckduckgo.com/\\&")}; {print}' ${p} > $p.bak
    awk '/last_prompted_google_url/ {sub(/google.com\//,"duckduckgo.com/\\&")}; {print}' ${p}.bak > ${p}
```

Comment: I get a “permission denied” error on 2nd line — so perhaps a silly question: do I need to root my phone to be able to do it?

Comment: You might want to make sure that the first line's path actually exists. If it doesn't, then that command would fail. I may have ran this command on a rooted phone, but can't recall for sure (my last two phones haven't been rooted, but this post may have been from the phone before those two)

Answer (score 2):

With newer versions, you need to open the search engine first, do a search, then Chrome will add it on its list.

If you then go to Settings -> Search engine, the search engine you visited will be listed in the Recently visited section.

Answer (score -2):

> You can configure the default search engine for the address bar by going to Chrome menu > Settings > (Basics) Search engine.

[Search The Web](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1725205?hl=en)

Comment: I don't see any placeholder to add duckduckgo.com as an option over there

Comment: ? Isn't the option custom for you to type anything? I don't have Google Chrome installed, and i believe it is incompatible with my X8, i can't try for myself... but it should work?

Comment: I made the question because obviously I don't see that option

Comment: I can't help you much further because my X8 isn't compatible with the app for me to test it, however, if you feel with time and want to read more, [these guys](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2097329&page=2) Were/Are having the same problem...